# Circle with question mark instead of font awesome's icons

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

I have a problem when trying to use font awesome icons on WordPress website. No metter what icon I use I see only blinking circle with question mark. Never had issue like this before. 
[Screenshot with icons I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5wiF.png)

Comment: do you have included the font awesome CSS?

Comment: it's looks like some other css rules overriding default font awesome rules. can you confirm that fontawesome.css file is loading? and provide css rules related to the icons in the screenshot. also, provide html markup for fonts

Comment: do you see errors in browser console? you might have `http` Font Awesome link on `https` site.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In my case it was that i wrote invalid prefix for brands icon:

```
<i className="fa fa-instagram">
```

instead of

```
<i className="fab fa-instagram">
```

Version 4 just had one prefix — fa, but older versions have 4 prefixes.

See upgrade notes: [upgrading-from-4](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/upgrading-from-4)

Comment: Err, "but older versions have 4 prefixes." - I guess you meant *newer* versions ;-) (aka FA5)

Comment: Thanks. in my case I used "fa" instead of "far". Based Your Idea of course.

Answer (score 6):

Everything was added. But problem was in second font-awesome script that was manualy added. After deleting this problem dissapears.

Answer (score 4):

Circle with question mark is a **missing icon indicator** to help with debugging missing icons or mistyped icon names. Read more on https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/setup/configuration#showmissingicons

It means FontAwesome was installed correctly but the **icon you try to use do not exists**.

Probably you try to use old className. From version 5 FontAwesome uses new prefixes. Version 4 just had one prefix - `fa`. Version 5 has four prefixes to let us set the style of icon.

Example:

```html
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>  <!-- version 4's syntax -->
<i class="fas fa-camera-retro"></i> <!-- version 5's syntax -->
```

Read more about upgrading from Version 4 on: 
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4

Comment: This was my issue, but because I was looking at the wrong version list of free icons within the font awesome site! Seems like different versions have different available icons and names

Answer (score 2):

It may be because you are not using the latest version of fontawesome. Update your version and try again.

Comment: Updating the version worked for me. The version setting has sandwormed from the CDN to **kits**:  https://fontawesome.com/kits/  Today it's 5.14.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem (with fontawesome 5) until I realised I was only using fontawesome CSS and linked a JS as well. Using *FA* locally (and downloading the full pack) solves the problems as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case; the issue was the FA CSS being loaded was a different version to the JS.

Ensure both FA CSS and JS versions match up to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found that just copying the codes off the font awesome site rarely works. Just did it --including the cdn code they gave me and had this same result of a flashing exclamation point. Changing it from far to fa fixed it. Guess they do not manage their site very well.

Comment: Their site is fine; you copied the code for version 5; your site is loading version 4.

Answer (score 0):

Download Font Awesome Plugin and do the following settings
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just experienced this and it was as simple as referencing an icon that didn't actually exist (`far fa-remove`).
Not sure if it was a mistake and it never worked, or if I've changed versions of Font Awesome at some point and the icon was later removed/renamed.

I suggest a search of fontawesome.com for your expected icon as a first step.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to a plugin conflict. I had the same issue. My icons worked fine for anyone who was logged in, but became flashing question marks when they were logged out. I ran the Fontawesome conflict scanner in the Troubleshooting section of the FA settings and it turned out to be a conflict with the plugin for 3CX Live Chat. When I disabled it, everything worked. I'll be notifying 3CX Live Chat about the issue. Hope this helps someone dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Generally - FontAwesome website is by default showing all icons.
Non-free without subscription shows as a question mark in a circle.
To use free ones find the "Free" button on a web page or use this link:
https://fontawesome.com/search?q=term&o=r&m=free

Comment: This reads like "Your problem might be that you do X. So the solution might be to do exactly the same, X." Please rephrase to avoid that confusion.